# Why thekendo column chart on x-axis values are getting displayed not in order

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

JS Bin

```
    <div id="example" class="k-content">
        <div class="chart-wrapper">
            <div id="chart"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var internetUsers = [ {
                    "Month": "1",
                    "year": "2010",
                    "value": 1
                }, {
                    "Month": "2",
                    "year": "2010",
                    "value": 2
                }, {
                    "Month": "3",
                    "year": "2010",
                    "value": 3
                }, {
                    "Month": "4",
                    "year": "2010",
                    "value": 4

                }, {
                    "Month": "5",
                    "year": "2010",
                    "value": 5
                },
                                {
                    "Month": "6",
                    "year": "2010",
                    "value": 6
                }, {
                    "Month": "7",
                    "year": "2010",
                    "value": 7
                }, {
                    "Month": "8",
                    "year": "2010",
                    "value": 8

                },
                                {
                    "Month": "9",
                    "year": "2010",
                    "value": 9
                }, {
                    "Month": "10",
                    "year": "2010",
                    "value": 10
                }, {
                    "Month": "11",
                    "year": "2010",
                    "value": 11

                },
                                {
                    "Month": "12",
                    "year": "2010",
                    "value": 17117.00
                },
                                 {
                    "Month": "1",
                    "year": "2011",
                    "value": 12
                }, {
                    "Month": "2",
                    "year": "2011",
                    "value": 13
                }, {
                    "Month": "3",
                    "year": "2011",
                    "value": 4
                }, {
                    "Month": "4",
                    "year": "2011",
                    "value": 6

                }, {
                    "Month": "5",
                    "year": "2011",
                    "value": 24
                },
                                {
                    "Month": "6",
                    "year": "2011",
                    "value": 3
                }, {
                    "Month": "7",
                    "year": "2011",
                    "value": 35
                }, {
                    "Month": "8",
                    "year": "2011",
                    "value": 34

                },
                                {
                    "Month": "9",
                    "year": "2011",
                    "value": 22
                }, {
                    "Month": "10",
                    "year": "2011",
                    "value": 21
                }, {
                    "Month": "11",
                    "year": "2011",
                    "value": 215

                },
                                {
                    "Month": "12",
                    "year": "2011",
                    "value": 12
                }];

            function createChart() {
                $("#chart").kendoChart({
                    theme: $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "default",
                    dataSource: {
                        data: internetUsers,
                        group: {
                         field: "year"
                        },
                      sort: {
                            field: "year",
                            dir: "asc"
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: "Sales"
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: "bottom"
                    },
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        type: "column"

                    },
                    series: [{

                        field: "value"


                    }],
                  valueAxis: {
                        labels: {
                            format: "{0}$"
                        },

                        line: {
                            visible: false
                        },
                        axisCrossingValue: 0
                    },
                    categoryAxis: {
                        field: "Month"

                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        visible: true,
                        format: "{0}%",
                        template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
                    }
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Initialize the chart with a delay to make sure
                    // the initial animation is visible
                    createChart();

                    $("#example").bind("kendo:skinChange", function(e) {
                        createChart();
                    });
                }, 400);
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

http://jsbin.com/oxakup/17/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sort your dataSource by month instead of year like the following:

```
sort: { field: "Month", dir: "asc" }
```

Now your months are sorting correctly based off your values, although the month data types are string instead of number, hence the reason this will now sort by 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3 etc..

You can work around this by fixing it in your JSON data source, but if you're unable to change that, you can use the following to format the data in the dataSource before processing:

```
schema: {
  data: function(response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      response[i].Month = new Number(response[i].Month);
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hai,Instead of 1,2,3 I need to display as Jan ,Feb means what I need to do.I have tried with the label format labels: {
                                format: "MMMM"
                            } but not displaying .

Comment: Well, there's no automatic way for anything to know that your numbers are representative of a month. You would have to manually map the number to a string, or manually map it to a date object and then use the string format option to output the value you want.

Comment: Ok,But now I am working with remote data which have year and month ,value.But now you have to create a function that returns 3 letter month and put that in the template.

Comment: Have a look at the answer on your own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586680/how-to-get-the-month-names-in-kendo-chart-by-using-function - That should give you enough information to figure out the correct method that you need for your situation

Comment: Yes,but I didnt got labels: {
        template: "#=monthNames[value - 1]#"
    } why to use value-1 and in X axixs if I have configured .But Out put i am getting as jan dec feb nov march sep

Comment: That's probably because you're still sorting by year instead of month as per my above answer

Comment: Ok.I have a another doubt I have Three series fields sa,sb,sc and for each month (legend is 2012/2013).I have configured categiores with months thats working fine .Now getting issue with legends.Getting repeated legend series as 2012,2013,2012,2013,2012,2013

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33342/discussion-between-kvs-and-boniestlawyer)