# How to get the month names in kendo chart by using function

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

How to create a function to get the month as Jan,feb.. displayed in kendo chart  x axis.

```
var internetUsers = [ {
                            "Month": "1",
                            "year": "2010",
                            "value": 1
                        }, {
                            "Month": "2",
                            "year": "2010",
                            "value": 2
                        }, {
                            "Month": "3",
                            "year": "2010",
                            "value": 3
                        }, {
                            "Month": "4",
                            "year": "2010",
                            "value": 4

                        }, {
                            "Month": "5",
                            "year": "2010",
                            "value": 5
                        },
                                        {
                            "Month": "6",
                            "year": "2010",
                            "value": 6
                        }, {
                            "Month": "7",
                            "year": "2010",
                            "value": 7
                        }, {
                            "Month": "8",
                            "year": "2010",
                            "value": 8

                        }];

                    function createChart() {
                        $("#chart").kendoChart({
                            theme: $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "default",
                            dataSource: {
                                data: internetUsers,
                                group: {
                                 field: "year"
                                },
                              sort: {
                                    field: "year",
                                    dir: "asc"
                                }
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: "Sales"
                            },
                            legend: {
                                position: "bottom"
                            },
                            seriesDefaults: {
                                type: "column"

                            },
                            series: [{

                                field: "value"


                            }],
                          valueAxis: {
                                labels: {
                                    format: "{0}$"
                                },

                                line: {
                                    visible: false
                                },
                                axisCrossingValue: 0
                            },
                            categoryAxis: {
                                field: "Month"

                            },

                            tooltip: {
                                visible: true,
                                format: "{0}%",
                                template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            // Initialize the chart with a delay to make sure
                            // the initial animation is visible
                            createChart();

                            $("#example").bind("kendo:skinChange", function(e) {
                                createChart();
                            });
                        }, 400);
                    });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use kendoui's time format function:

```
kendo.toString(new Date(2000, value, 1), "MMMM"); // if value = 9, it would output September
```

Check out kendoui's date format page. It is VERY helpful.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting

Answer (score 0):

First add an array to hold the month names, like so:

```
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug"];
```

then modify the categoryAxis to use this array

```
categoryAxis: {
    field: "Month",
    labels: {
        template: "#=monthNames[value - 1]#"
    },
},
```

Comment: But not getting the months in order