# Dynamic series legend in Knockout-Kendo Chart

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-kendo, kendo-chart

I have a collection of objects with data that need to be displayed as dynamic kendo charts.  I am using Niemeyer's Knockout-Kendo library with a KO observablearray. I use a relative value to chart the data onto the kendo chart, but I need to display the actual text value that is associated with the data.  Kendo has a template attribute that can accomplish this but I have hit a roadblock making it work in the Knockout-Kendo library.

**Fiddle**

Here's [a functioning Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlesticks66/9MW9g/) with data

**Goal**

Use a lookup value for display in the ValueAxis and ToolTip of the chart

**References**

[Kendo Label Template docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-valueAxis.labels.template)

[Kendo Chart with a function for label example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586680/how-to-get-the-month-names-in-kendo-chart-by-using-function)

[Niemeyer Knockout-Kendo Chart docs](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/dataviz/Chart.html)

**Data Snippet**

```
var theData =[{
    "TrackerName": "Fruits",
    "Trackers": [{
        "TrackerName": "Fruits",
        "TrackerDate": "2014-02-12T00:00:00",
        "OptionText": "5-7 servings",
        "RelativeValue": 3
    },
    {
        "TrackerName": "Fruits",
        "TrackerDate": "2014-02-13T00:00:00",
        "OptionText": "5-7 servings",
        "RelativeValue": 3
    },
       etc];
```

**HTML and Data Bindings**

```
<div data-bind="foreach:AllTrackers">
    <h3 data-bind="text:TrackerName"> </h3>
    <!-- ko with: Trackers -->
    <div data-bind="kendoChart:
                    {
                        data: $data,
                        chartArea: {
                            height:100
                        },
                        series: [
                            {
                                type: 'line',
                                style:'smooth',
                                field: 'RelativeValue',
                                markers: {
                                    visible: true,
                                    background: '#c0c0c0',
                                    size: 10
                                },
                                tooltip: {
                                    visible: true,
                                    background: '#f0f0f0'
                                }
                            }],
                        seriesColors: ['midnightblue'],
                        valueAxis: {
                            labels: {
                                template: 'Help #=value#'
                            },
                            line: {
                                visible: false
                            },
                            min: 1,
                            max: 4,
                            majorUnit: 1
                        }
                        ,
                        categoryAxis: {
                            categories:$parent.CategoryDates,
                            majorGridLines: {
                                visible: false
                            }
                        }
                    }">
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to expose your helper function globally, so that the Kendo template code can find it. The fiddle JS code is running in the `onload` function, so your `getOptionText` function is not global.

You could do something like:

```
window.myApp = {
    helpers: {
        getOptionText: function(q ){
            //these are not the real values, but you get the idea
            if(q===1){
                return 'Bare minimum';
            }
            if (q ===2){
                return 'Some effort ';
            }
            if (q ===3){
                return 'Good  ';
            }
            if (q ===4){
                return 'Great ';
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then, use a template like: '#=myApp.helpers.getOptionText(value)#'

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/X2WBL/